# Embed a linked copy of a slide from other Powerpoint presentation in another Powerpoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The problem is this:

```
I´ve got two Powerpoint presentations.
I want to link the second slide of one presentation into the another presentation.
How I do this? 

I can embed a presentation into another but I want to select the second slide, anyone can help?
```

Comment: Do you want to embed or link?  Can't have both.

Comment: I mean link. The thing is to have the two presentations synchronized.

Comment: This is more a question for SuperUser but since we're here, try this:  Put the "source" presentation into slide show view.  Add a new slide to the "target" presentation and leave it in normal view. Select the slide you want to link to in the Source presentation and copy it.  Switch to the Target presentation and choose Paste Special | Link.  Resize the pasted slide to fit and save.  That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have two powerpoint files opened.

In the source powerpoint:

Click on the slide preview and copy.

In the target powerpoint:

Create a new slide and then select the home ribbon.

Below paste there are more options, click on paste Special and then Paste Link.

One option must appear: 'Microsoft Powerpoint Slide Object'

Resize the object to fill the entire slide and it´s done.

Comment: Would that mean if the slide is edited in the source slideshow that the edits will appear in the pasted version? Or will this just paste the slide content?